# How to exclude the default lib coming from $GRAILS_HOME/libs/ in Grails 2.4.3

Tags: grails, dependencies, guava, grails-plugin, buildconfig

I am using Grails 2.4.3
I have `com.google.guava:guava:10.0.1` lib included in $GRAILS_HOME/libs/ and all dependencies in $GRAILS_HOME/libs/ are included in my app by following code in my BuildConfig.groovy

```
    grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
        // inherit Grails' default dependencies
        inherits("global") {
    }
    .....
    }
```

Now the question is that I want to use the latest version of `com.google.guava:guava:21.0` so how can I exclude the default `com.google.guava:guava:10.0.1` lib coming from  $GRAILS_HOME/libs/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the dependencies in the BuildConfig.groovy like in Docs explained: http://docs.grails.org/2.4.3/guide/conf.html#configurationsAndDependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
}
```